# Jquery get ... mixing json and non-json data?

Tags: jquery, json, struts2

I have something like this on a jsp page

```
   var json_text = JSON.stringify(rows, null, 2);
   $.get("/myapp/CountQuery.action", 
        {output: output,
         table: table,
         stringRows: json_text
        },
              function(data) {                
                     var text = JSON.stringify(data);
                 alert('Here is the data received ' + text);
              });
```

I use json2.js for my JSON needs whichs works very well.  So, the `stringRows` I am passing is json data.  The `output` and `table` however are taken from the value of textfield elements on my page.  It does not make sense to mix `stringRows` with `output` and `table` given what they represent.  Perhaps if need be, I can create a second json object containing `output` and `table`.  In the function, I am getting back JSON data sent to me by a Struts 2 action with result type JSON which gives me back valid JSON data.

Here is what is happening.  If I remove both `output` and `table` from my jquery call, I see log messages in oc4j and everything looks good.  If I remove just `stringRows`, I see log messages in oc4j and everything looks good.  If I have `output`, `table` and `stringRows`, the alert message does get activated, but I do not see any logs indicating something is not quite right.  JSON data is present in the `text` variable in my function above, but I don't know what is actually happening.

So my question is: Is mixing the json and non-json data inherently bad and if so which level is being fooled?  I have seen other user `'json'` in their jquery get calls, so I imagine it might have something to do with this.

**EDIT**

Too long for a comment, so here is my response:

@kingjiv I develop constantly in ie, so sometimes I do forget to check the logs.  So running in chrome, the message I get is `GET http://localhost:8080/myapp/CountQuery.action?output=APPN%2CBSO%2CLI&table=mytable&stringRows=%5B%0A++%5B%0A++++%22%22%2C%0A++++%22%22%2C%0A++++%22ADD%22%2C%0A++++%22%3D%22%2C%0A++++%22A%22%2C%0A++++%22%22%2C%0A++++%22AND%22%2C%0A++++%22%22%0A++%5D%2C%0A++%5B%0A++++%22%22%2C%0A++++%22%22%2C%0A++++%22D%2FR%22%2C%0A++++%22%3D%22%2C%0A++++%22D%22%2C%0A++++%22%22%2C%0A++++%22AND%22%2C%0A++++%22%22%0A++%5D%2C%0A++%5B%0A++++%22%22%2C%0A++++%22%22%2C%0A++++%22CIVPER%22%2C%0A++++%22%3D%22%2C%0A++++%22N%22%2C%0A++++%22%22%2C%0A++++%22AND%22%2C%0A++++%22%22%0A++%5D%0A%5D 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Are there any messages in the js console when it doesn't work?

Comment: Since the JSON is represented as a string, there is no difference between it and any other string of text you send to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by kingjiv was all it took to get my mind moving.  Here is what I changed it to

```
   var json_text = JSON.stringify(rows, null, 2);
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myapp/CountQuery.action", 
        data: "output=" + output + "&table=" + table + "&stringRows=" + json_text, 
        success: function(msg) {                  
           var text = JSON.stringify(msg);
       alert(text);
        }
   });
```

Now, my logging is happy to report to me what I need to know.